# Compress and Serialize a large HashMap in memory

Tags: java, json, scala, serialization, compression

I have a large HashMap (~700 - 800MB) in memory. I want to serialize the data into a hash map and then compress it. What's the most efficient way to convert such an object to a Stream?
I current do the following:

```
inputMap: Map[String, Any]
inputMapToSerializeJsonUsingJackson: Array[Byte]
private def encodeGzip(bytes: Array[Byte]) = {
  val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
  val gos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos)
  try {
    gos.write(bytes)
  } finally {
    gos.close()
  }
  baos
}
```

Comment: 800M isn't really that large ... But what in the world are you going to do with a gzipped byte array in memory if I may ask???

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with hashmaps that large, you might want to consider one of the non-stock hashmap implementations which can have much better performance. For your usecase, consider something like [MapDb](http://www.mapdb.org/) which can compact data much more efficicently in memory and also back it with a disk file.